# Не закрывается Activity по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: android

```
btnBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        SecondActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
```

Разметка

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_orange_prev"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_orange_prev"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/alphabetPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите код `ImageButton` из разметки. И еще - зачем вы вызываете `finish()` у `SecondActivity.this`? Его можно вызвать отовсюду

Comment: добавила в вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте в xml добавить в `ImageView` ---> `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: но у меня там ImageButton

Comment: Тут два варианта - или сама кнопка не кликабельна, или не выполняется слушатель. Попробуйте проверить второе. Сделайте вывод в лог чего нибудь  если не заработает, то кнопка вообще не кликабельна.

Comment: Ой, да, извините, `ImageButton`

Comment: Разобралась. Спасибо

Comment: Если вы самостоятельно нашли решение, было бы просто замечательно, если бы вы оформили его как ответ (ответить на собственный вопрос). Это поможет другим быстрее решить аналогичную проблему